# Which test is uses this formula?

Tags: proportion

I'd like to know what is the name of the test, that uses this formula.
The test is something that is called "alternative analysis" ot "analysis of alternative" (that is called in my language literally, I found it old statistical book. It tests and compares proportions. Does anybody knows how this test is called? 
In fact I need to compare proportions in a sample, i.e. total size 100, 27 are "yes", others are "no". I was told I need to use this formula.

[image]

Comment: Please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=test+proportions+two+sample+formula).

Comment: You should have two samples, not just one as you imply. That is what the subscripts refer to.

Comment: The formula is a statistic for a two sample proportions test.

Comment: Glen_b, could you elaborate some more on this? Do you know such test? As far as I know usually z-test is applied when comparing two sample proportions.